# Retrieve value of a particular key from a nested JSON Object in Java

Tags: json

I  have a JSON Object as below:

```
{  
   "_embedded":{  
      "user":{  
         "passwordChanged":"01/10/2017",
         "profile":{  
            "firstName":"xyz",
            "lastName":"abc",
            "timeZone":"America/Los_Angeles",
            "login":"xyz@abc.com",
            "locale":"en"
         },
         "id":"1234567a"
      }
   },
   "token":"120392w",
   "expiresAt":"01/12/2022",
   "status":"active"
}
```

I want to iterate this object and retrieve the value of "timeZone". How do I do it in JAVA?

Answer (score 0):

Use gson to parse the json to a class:

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder.create();
    UserData userData = gson.fromJson("your json here",UserData.class);
    System.out.println(userData.get_embeded().getUser().getProfile().getTimeZone());
```

Note that you'll have to create the class you are parsing the json to.

Comment: Thanks. Is there something I can achieve without using Gson.

Comment: You can use praseJSON refer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)